# Textbox cursor is not blinking when we visit particular screen and come back to main screen

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, .net

This is the HTML and Javascript code:

```js
SetFocus('txtExternalNotes', 1000, 1);
```

```html
<div id="extrnalBar" ng-model="ExternalNoteDiv" ng-hide="HideExternalNote">
  <span style="width:100px;" id="lblExternalNote">{{ExternalNoteText}}</span>
  <div style="padding-top:2px;">
    <textarea id="txtExternalNotes" ng-model="ExternalNotes" ng-readonly="ExternalNotesReadonly" maxlength="2000" ng-minlength="0" ng-trim="false" class="k-textbox" tabindex="4" style="height:75px; width: 100%;"></textarea>
    <label>
    <span style="float:left;color:#a8a8a8;" id="lblENMaxCharacters"> {{Labels.EN_MaxCharacters}}</span>
    <span class="{{spnLength}}"><label id="lblENTextLength">{{Labels.EN_TextLength}}</label> {{ExternalNotes.length}}</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried this but still not getting the output

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('textbox').focus();
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Consider using the [<>] button in the editor for formatting HTML and Javascript code. (I have done that with your question.)

Comment: Your code working with 2 adjustments-a) add jquery library file,b) create `setFous()` function : https://jsfiddle.net/ae0dg56v/

Comment: Instead of `$('textbox').focus();` use  `$('textarea').focus(); `